# Pdfjs get PDF file from S3 working on Safari, but not working on chrome and firefox with error 404 not found, Missing PDF Exception

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, pdf.js, pdfjs-dist

We store the PDF file above AWS S3, and access it through Cloudfront. To access the PDF file, I have to call api: `/api/preview-file/30.json`
But on chrome and firefox I get the error: "MissingPDFException", but on Safari everything works fine, which is confusing.
I have searched but have no answer, looking forward to your help. Thank you!

Configuration:

- Web browser and its version: Chrome Version 89.0.4389.114 (Official Build) (x86_64), Firefox 87.0 (64-bit)
- Operating system and its version: Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.6
- PDF.js version: 2.6.347

What went wrong? (add screenshot)

- Firefox:
  [image: Screen Shot 2021-04-12 at 14 08 34]
- Chrome:
  [image: Screen Shot 2021-04-12 at 14 13 21]

My code: PreviewFile.vue

```
import * as pdfjsLib from 'pdfjs-dist'
import * as pdfjsWorker from 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.entry'

pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = pdfjsWorker

export default {
    name: 'PreviewFile',
    mounted () {
        // const url = this.$route.query.q
        pdfjsLib.getDocument('/api/preview-file/30.json').promise.then(pdf => {
            const viewer = document.getElementById('pdf-viewer')

            for (let pageNum = 1; pageNum <= pdf.numPages; pageNum++) {
                const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
                canvas.className = 'pdf-page-canvas'
                viewer.appendChild(canvas)
                pdf.getPage(pageNum).then(page => {
                    const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: 2 })
                    canvas.height = viewport.height
                    canvas.width = viewport.width
                    page.render({ canvasContext: canvas.getContext('2d'), viewport: viewport })
                })
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Network on firefox: 404

[image: Screen Shot 2021-04-12 at 14 47 35]

Network on safari: OK

[image: Screen Shot 2021-04-12 at 14 45 52]